# What are the errors in this code?

Tags: c++

```
void main (void)
{
    char name [2] [30], number [2] [10];
    char << "Please type your first name, a blank, and last name) << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Name=" <<name << endl;
    cout << "Please type a number, press the return key, and another number << endl;
    cin >> number [0] >> endl;
    cout << number << endl; 
}
```

Comment: I found the error: `void main(void)`

Comment: This is the classic example of the new definition of "too localised": This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: And some people still care to answer them?  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Too many to mention, but we're not here to act as a homework service. Examine the output of your compiler then tackle them one at a time:

---

```
qq.cpp:4:13: warning: missing terminating " character
qq.cpp:4: error: missing terminating " character
qq.cpp:7:13: warning: missing terminating " character
qq.cpp:7: error: missing terminating " character
qq.cpp:1: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
qq.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
qq.cpp:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<<’ token
qq.cpp:6: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
qq.cpp:6: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
qq.cpp:8: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
```

---

At a bare minimum:

- No `using` clause or `std::` prefixes.
- `char` is not a stream.
- No closing quotes on some of the string literals.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parenthesis instead of a double quotation mark at the end of `"Please type your first name, a blank, and last name)`

Comment: Too many things to complain about, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't end the string with a " as in

```
char << "Please type your first name, a blank, and last name) << endl;
```

and

```
cout << "Please type a number, press the return key, and another number << endl;
```

it should be:

```
int main (void)
{
char name [2] [30], number [2] [10];
char << "Please type your first name, a blank, and last name)" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "Name=" <<name << endl;
cout << "Please type a number, press the return key, and another number" << endl;
cin >> number [0] >> endl;
cout << number << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char << "Please type your first name, a blank, and last name) << endl;
```

and

```
cout << "Please type a number, press the return key, and another number << endl;
```

are both missing end double quotes

```
char << "Please type your first name, a blank, and last name)" << endl;
cout << "Please type a number, press the return key, and another number" << endl
```

Comment: That first one may have something _else_ wrong :-) Hint, `char` is a keyword.